# Why does Firefox sometimes cache my CSS & Javascript code, even though it has changed?

Tags: html, css, caching, browser, assets

On my product site, Firefox sometimes "doesnt detect" changes in my CSS & Javascript code. Rather it loads the old versions, so it seems that I need to clear the cache. In a situation like this, what should I do? This relates to the latest Firefox (16.0.1 at the time of this writing.)

EDIT!

I forgot to say it mistakes for the localhost css files. I meant, theres an old js file, I update it, upload it, and on product server firefox thinks its the localhost file.
The way I include files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/xyz.css" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using a server-side language you could use a trick.
You can append a string after .css/.js. In PHP for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css?t=<?= time(); ?>" />
```

It changes every page reload.

Take a look at this article about [cache busting](http://www.adopsinsider.com/ad-ops-basics/what-is-a-cache-buster-and-how-does-it-work/).

Comment: This (Cache-busting) is by far the best approach!

Comment: Oh yes! It works... but in production could speed down the page loading

Comment: True, I've only ever applied version numbers in production, but dev-enviro it's a must :)

Comment: For development `ctrl+r` in your browser will do a hard refresh that clears the cache.  Also you can disable the cache in your browser.

Comment: If pulling the time from your server is causing page load issues, get a new host. Version numbers are great if you have a single header file and if you remember to do it.

Comment: Don't use the current time. If you can, either use the modification time of the file or (better) the md5 hash of its contents. That way browsers can still use a cached version as long as the content hasn't changed (which is exactly what you want).

Comment: In some browsers it is `ctrl+shift+r`

Answer (score 9):

You can use a technique called "cache busting" where you attach a query string to your call to your css/js file.  You then update the query string whenever you update your css/js.

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css?ver=1" />
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in several other answers you want to have a unique identifier for your static assets *based on the content* i.e. the identifier changes if and only if the content changes. That way browsers can still use a cached version of a resource as long as the content hasn't changed - which is exactly what you want. This technique is called *static asset versioning*.

So don't use the current time or a random number/string. If you can, either use the modification time of the file or (better) the md5 hash of its contents. You can append this identifier as a query string (which will be ignored) or ([better](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/versioning_static_assets_with_urlrewritefilter)) append it to the filename before the extension.

To contrast this with and clear the confusion about the technique of [cache busting](http://www.adopsinsider.com/ad-ops-basics/what-is-a-cache-buster-and-how-does-it-work/) mentioned in some other answers: *cache busting* is a technique used by advertisers to force the browser to always reload a resource so the advertiser can measure the number of ad impressions by the number of times the resource is requested. This is easily accomplished by using a random number. You *don't* normally want to use this for your static assets.

Answer (score 2):

You can append a version at the end of the css/js you send accross.

For Example

Instead of `www.foo.com/js/javascript.js`, send `www.foo.com/js/javascript.js?v=1` and 
Instead of `www.foo.com/css/style.css`, send `www.foo.com/css/style.js?v=1`

Answer (score 2):

- You can use a meta tag to force the refreshing. `<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">`, or `<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">`.
- You can force the HTTP header: `Cache-control: no-cache` or `Pragma: no-cache`.
- You can append a random query string to your CSS and JavaScript files.

Comment: The no cache isn't the best option for performance though. You'll take a hit on page speeds.

Comment: I agree with you on this, sire.

Answer (score 1):

Just gotta clear the cache or hard refresh (Ctrl+F5) I'm afraid.

Another option is to simply change the file name of the JS or CSS file so that FF doesn't recognize it as a cached file (e.g. rename style.css to style2.css).

Answer (score 1):

`style.css?randomnumber` will asure the loading