# What kind of url is this http://example.com/style.css?v=024741259dd2

Tags: javascript, html, css

Nowadays In most of the sites i am seeing url  like this

http://example.com/style.css?v=024741259dd2

Where style.css is appended with some text. What is this appended text is it some version number or date and time? If yes how is it generated?
What is the significance of this?

Comment: It isn't necessarry for you...

Comment: Most sites uses this to remember the version of style

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076627

Comment: It may be generated automatically... for disallow cache

Comment: You can generate it simple

Comment: If you want to generate if for disallow cache, you can do the following in your <head>:

`<?php $amountOfDigits = 6;`

` $numbers = range(0,9);`

` shuffle($numbers);`

` for($i = 0;$i < $amountOfDigits;$i++)`

`    $digits .= $numbers[$i];`

` ?>`
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=<?php echo $digits; ?>" type="text/css" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is probably a "random" number (e.g. a file checksum, or the SHA of a commit under a versioning system, or the resource timestamp in MD5 format, or...)  generated automatically on server-side as a cachebusting technique. The purpose is to invalidate the browser cache for that resource if you've already loaded it and a change was made.

As example, I always use that technique while I am developing a website with Jekyll and Jekyll-assets, so I can be sure to always see my recent changes without reloading my javascript and stylesheets file from the cache.

Comment: Why do people want to do that. JS and CSS are meant to be cached isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but once you update your styles and javascript files you want to be sure that users use the latest versions.

Comment: yes, but the idea is to change that parameter only when a change is made and not on every page refresh.

Comment: Ordinarily it's not a random number, but e.g. the last-modified timestamp or the file's md5 - so that the url only changes when the file's contents do.

Comment: it can also be a substring of the file checksum or it can be the sha of the commit if that file is under a versioning system. Or it can be generated by a `rand()`. It depends on the system who generated it