# Chrome and Firefox displaying different stylesheets

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

When I make an edit to the stylesheet of my site, the change appears in Chrome (I load the CSS file in the browser, so I can see the edit is there). When I open the CSS file in Firefox, the edit is not there. I understand browsers will render code differently, but how is it possible that two browsers can open the same CSS file and display two different sets of code?

I tried:

- deleting Firefox's cache and restarting the program
- deleting the old stylesheet via FTP and uploading an edited one
- I checked if the site had a CDN that was perhaps serving the old
  file, but the site has no CDN.

Comment: Check if [THIS POST](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13076663/2968762) helps

Comment: It might be a request handling issue... There's a strange bug at my workplace where opening the prod version of our site from on our network occasionally hands you dev instead, but it's not annoying enough (and us not big enough) to get any sort of priority on fixing. If F5F5 doesn't solve the caching issue, the problem is probably not Chrome vs Firefox, but something upstream from them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Not certain if the source of the problem was the browser (probably Firefox being stubborn), or the server not sending the right file, but 30 minutes later, the problem somehow solved itself. Thanks again.